# About category theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Let $C$ be a category and $f:A\to B$ is a morphism.

If $f$ is isomorphism, then exist unique morphism $g:B\to A$ such that $g\circ f=1_A$ and $f\circ g=1_B.$

Can someone give me a hint to prove this, please?

Comment: What do you define as isomorphism then?

Comment: @JJ1993 why, is there a contradiction in the problem?

Comment: The "property" you stated is the definition of an isomorphism in a category.

Comment: @JJ1993 oh, there's no problem then, so the exercise start in the 'If...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $f:A\to B$ is an isomorphism (that's the "if" part).

By definition of isomorphism, there exists a morphism $g:B\to A$ such that $g\circ f=1_A$ and $f\circ g=1_B.$

So the only thing left to prove is the uniqueness of $g$.

Thus, suppose $h:B\to A$ is a morphism such that $h\circ f=1_A$ and $f\circ h=1_B.$

The goal is to show $g=h$.

It's very simple . . .

\begin{align*}
&g\circ f=1_A\\[4pt]
\implies\;&(g\circ f)\circ h=1_A \circ h\\[4pt]
\implies\;&g\circ (f \circ h)=1_A \circ h\\[4pt]
\implies\;&g\circ 1_B =1_A \circ h\\[4pt]
\implies\;&g=h\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Comment: it's very simple . . . (for you)

Comment: @AnneliseToft it's very simple if one read carefully the theory and try to understand it.

Comment: @Xam So are you saying that this particular exercise is very simple if one...? or in general Category theory is simple if one read carefully the theory...?

Comment: @AnneliseToft I was referring to this particular exercise.

Comment: @Xam yea I suppose that, because everybody says category theory it's very difficult